Level mean from natural logarithm mean
Suppose I have a random sample $X_i$ where the values $x_i$ are strictly positive. I calculate the mean of the transformed variable $t_i = \ln x_i$ as $\bar{t} = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n t_i}{n} \approx 9.670$.

What is the corresponding level mean? Is it simply $e^{9.670} \approx 15835.35$?
Does it change anything if the mean is weighted $\bar{t}_w = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n w_i t_i}{\sum_{i=1}^n w_i}$?

In my case it seems to overpredict. If I do a rough calculation $15835.35 \cdot n$ I get sums which are much larger than the total sum.

There's also the issue that summation in the log scale is multiplication in the original scale (you are calculating a geometric mean).
